# Cannot push new repository to github

Tags: git, github, repository, git-push

I made a project and a .gitignore file then the following:

```
git init
git config --global user.name "username"
git config --global user.email email
```

from the directory where the project is:

```
git add .
git commit -m "first"
git remote add origin https://github.com/username/projectname.git
git push -u origin master (also tried using main)
```

It then proceeded to reject my username and password. I did some reading and got an access token but it still failed to connect.

```
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '140.82.114.4' to the list 
of known hosts.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

git log gives me:

```
commit <some hash> (HEAD -> main)
author: me
date: today
```

git status:

```
On branch main
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

I copied and pasted the https address github gives in the repository; the repository certainly exists. Some people recommended using the SSH instead of https but that didn't work either.

I don't have any firewalls and I am the admin.

Please help this is driving me crazy

Comment: You quote an `https://` URL, but then you quote errors that clearly came from ssh, not https. So you're mixing up different authentication methods and results here, which makes it harder for anyone to help you. See [ask]. As for ssh access, GitHub have their own suggestions for debugging: see https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/testing-your-ssh-connection

Comment: I mentioned that I tried both methods, both https and ssh, but neither worked for me. Initially I followed the instructions here https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/deploy/
I'm just trying whatever I can find; I just want it to work.

Comment: OK. I personally dislike the https method (it has way too many moving parts, each of which can break in a different way) so I recommend sticking with ssh. Using ssh, use GitHub's suggested debugging trick: run `ssh -Tv git@github.com` (use as many v's as you like here; replace `git@github.com` with whatever you use as your ssh URL user@host part, if you're using fancy ssh configuration tricks). GitHub will take the incoming public key and look it up and authenticate it, if they can, and will then tell you who that public key names, on GitHub's systems.

Comment: If GitHub say: `Hi <username>! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.` you know that this ssh key *works* and declares, to GitHub, that you *are* the user `<username>` (fill in the angle brackety bits with whatever they printed). From here all you need to do is make sure that the ssh that Git runs is the same ssh you just ran. On Unix-like systems, that's usually just automatic; on modern Windows systems, you may have to tell your Windows Git to use the Windows ssh.

Comment: This last bit is because old Windows systems *did not come with an ssh* (or at least, not with a usable one) so the Git-for-Windows packaging people include *a* version of ssh. This version is subtly different from the modern Windows ssh, so that configuration for one is not configuration for the other. By telling Git (with `core.sshCommand`) to use the standard Windows Git, you'll get both to be the same. Alternatively, you can try running the Git-for-Windows ssh directly on the command line (how one does that, I'm not sure, I avoid Windows).

Comment: You are right; it just doesn't like the https way. Thanks for your tips about ssh, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Using the ssh way it worked, some useful commands in the answers

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).